# Selenium Как взять только одно значение атрибута srcset

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Мне нужно взять одну картинку допустим с размером 480w

```
image_Arr = driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='img.product-carousel__preview.ng-star-inserted') 
for i in image_Arr:
  print(i.get_attribute('srcset'))
```

[Сайт](https://www.mvideo.ru/products/televizor-toshiba-32v35ke-10029724)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне получить только одну картинку из этого каруселя картинок ?

Comment: Вам нужна конкретная картинка или произвольная? Можно не использовать цикл, а вывести первую\последнюю\произвольную картинку из массива или картинку с заданным индексом. Либо, проходя в цикле, проверять в if необходимые параметры картинки, - и выводить, если подходит.

Comment: `break` поставьте после печати - и будет только первая выводиться )

Comment: @АринаАригри он выводит весь список он не выводит как каждый элемент

Comment: @CrazyElf https://dpaste.com/GPF9ZNB3V

Comment: @АринаАригри https://dpaste.com/GPF9ZNB3V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно получить определенную картинку, как у вас написано 480w, можно взять содержимое атрибута srcset, разбить по запятым - split(","), а затем в цикле пробежаться по полученному списку. При этом проверяя endswith("480w"). И если найдете, забираете.
Можно так попробовать.
Ну и да, чтобы отсечь "480w", после того, как найдете, сделайте еще split() и заберите нулевой элемент.

Как это будет выглядеть в коде. Примерно так:

```
link = "48bb1.jpg 95w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/200/30063348bb1.jpg 200w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/480/30063348bb1.jpg 480w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/30063348bb1.jpg 1300w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/50/30063348bb2.jpg 50w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/65/30063348bb2.jpg 65w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/80/30063348bb2.jpg 80w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/95/30063348bb2.jpg 95w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/200/30063348bb2.jpg 200w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/480/30063348bb2.jpg 480w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/30063348bb2.jpg 1300w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/50/30063348bb3.jpg 50w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/65/30063348bb3.jpg 65w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/80/30063348bb3.jpg 80w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/95/30063348bb3.jpg 95w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/200/30063348bb3.jpg 200w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/480/30063348bb3.jpg 480w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/30063348bb3.jpg 1300w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/50/30063348bb4.jpg 50w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/65/30063348bb4.jpg 65w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/80/30063348bb4.jpg 80w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/95/30063348bb4.jpg 95w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/200/30063348bb4.jpg 200w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/480/30063348bb4.jpg 480w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/30063348bb4.jpg 1300w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/50/30063348bb5.jpg 50w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/65/30063348bb5.jpg 65w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/80/30063348bb5.jpg 80w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/95/30063348bb5.jpg 95w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/200/30063348bb5.jpg 200w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/480/30063348bb5.jpg 480w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/30063348bb5.jpg 1300w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/50/30063348bb6.jpg 50w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/65/30063348bb6.jpg 65w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/80/30063348bb6.jpg 80w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/95/30063348bb6.jpg 95w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/200/30063348bb6.jpg 200w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/480/30063348bb6.jpg 480w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/30063348bb6.jpg 1300w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/50/30063348bb7.jpg 50w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/65/30063348bb7.jpg 65w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/80/30063348bb7.jpg 80w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/95/30063348bb7.jpg 95w, " \
       "//img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/200/30063348bb7.jpg 200w, //img.mvideo.ru/Big/small_pic/480/30063348bb7.jpg 480w," \
       " //img.mvideo.ru/Big/30063348bb7.jpg 1300w".split(",")

list_480 = []
for item in link:
    if item.endswith("480w"):
        list_480.append(item.split()[0])


print(list_480[0])
```

Ну и на выходе получите отфильтрованный список. А уже из этого списка по индексу можете брать то, что захотите.
И еще, после того, как вы разобьете вашу строку и превратите в список, можно будет обратиться к любому элементу по индексу.